# How to pass value from Asp.Net for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How write x and y in my TextBox , I write this but not Work

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javaScript">
     function PantallaResolucion()
     {
         var x = screen.width.toString();
         var y = screen.height.toString();
         var xx = document.getElementById("HiddenField1");
         var yy = document.getElementById("HiddenField2");
         xx.value = x;
         yy.value = y;
     }
</script>
```

my asp.net code

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server"  />
```

C# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string c = "<script language='javascript'> PantallaResolucion(); </script> ";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PantallaResolucion();", c);
    TextBox1.Text = HiddenField1.Value.ToString() + "x" + HiddenField2.Value.ToString();// NOT WORK**
}
```

Comment: This code will not work. You messed up server side and client side logic. You have to right all this code on client side using javascript:
    function PantallaResolucion()
     {
    ....
     }
    PantallaResolucion();
    document.getElementById("text1").val = x+y or smth like this

Comment: How you define TextBox1 in asp.net page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
var xx = document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID%>");
var yy = document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField2.ClientID%>");
```

You could take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) to see an very detailed explanation about why this is needed. According to this link, in a few words:

> When a Web server control is rendered as an HTML element, the id
>   attribute of the HTML element is set to the value of the ClientID
>   property. The ClientID value is often used to access the HTML element
>   in client script by using the document.getElementById method.

A more clear approach to the whole problem it would be the following:

place this script at the bottom of your page, before the closing tag `</body>`

```
<script>
    function PantallaResolucion(){
        var width = screen.width.toString();
        var height = screen.height.toString();
        var hiddenFld1 = document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID%>");
        var hiddenFld2 = document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField2.ClientID%>");
        hiddenFld1.value = width;
        hiddenFld2.value = height;
        var textBox1 = document.getElemenetById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");  
        textBox1.value =  hiddenFld1.value + "x" + hiddenFld2.value;
    }
</script>
```

Then clear the statements from the `Page_Load` method. *By the way, I don't see any reason for having at all these two hidden inputs*. You could delete them and make the corresponding changes to the the above script.

Comment: you misunderstood the question, value must be passed from Javascript to Asp.net

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC I am sorry but I don't get you mean.

Comment: @AlenaKastsiukavets If I am not wrong, the OP, argues that a javascript script doesn't work. This script runs on the client and not on the server. Furthermore, I don't see an attempt to pass any value form the client to the server (js to asp.net). Correct?

Comment: As understood the goal is to calculate some value from hidden inputs in text field, it must be done fully on client side, if add 
var text = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>");
text.val = x + y; then we get the desired behavior I believe

Comment: @AlenaKastsiukavets I read again the whole question and I pointed out that you mentioned. So I edited my answer. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are no need for server side logic. You can do all on client side:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javaScript">
    var text = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>"); 
    var x = screen.width.toString();
    var y = screen.height.toString();
    text.value = x + ' ' + y;
</script>
```

I believe it is what you want